# Syntaxproblem passing to MultiBinding in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, multibinding, commandparameter

I try to pass from simple binding to MultiBinding for CommandParameter but can not find out the syntax for "{Binding}" in the following example for the multibinding example below. Thanks a lot for any hint !

Regards, Fabianus

```
    <Button Content="Add subevent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="100" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.AddEvent}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

CommandParameter with MultiBinding:

```
                    <Button Content="Add subevent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MinWidth="100" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.AddEvent}" >
                    <Button.CommandParameter>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource searchFilterConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="" />
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}"  Path="DataContext.SelectedProduct"  />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Button.CommandParameter>
                </Button>
```

Comment: `<Binding Path=""/>` is equivalent to `<Binding/>` or `{Binding}`. See here for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.path(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hey @Clemens, thanks so much ! This is it !
Don't know how to mark your answer as "the" aswer.